# How to checkout remote tag preserving remote branch name?

Tags: git, tags, branch

I'm trying to find a simple command to checkout a tag and preserve the branch name from where the tag belongs to. I am aware that tags are not necessarily attached to branches but rather commits. I'm also aware that I could achieve this in multiple commands, like:

1. Find branch name by parsing out response from: `git branch -a --contains <tag>`.
2. `git fetch`.
3. `git switch <branch-name-found-in-step-1>`.

But since you don't know what you don't know, I'm wondering if there's a one-line command to achieve this, something like: `git switch --tag <tag>` that automagically does what I want. If something like that does not exist, what would be the simplest way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: So you don't necessarily want to check out the branch at the specific commit tag was tagged? E.g. if the history is: commit1 -> commit2 (tagged) -> commit3 (latest commit on branch), then you want to check out commit3? Also, what branch do you want to check out if the tagged commit is on multiple branches?

Comment: @DMalan I do want to check out the branch at the specific tag commit BUT not detached. In my environment the tag will only "belong" to one branch, our git flow is automated and restricted, so a tag belonging to only one branch is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a shot at a one liner:

```
git switch -C $(git branch -r --format="%(refname:lstrip=3)" --contain <tag>) <tag>
```

Some explanations:

- `git branch -r ...`: only list remote branches, do not mix local and remote if some local branches were already present
- `--format="%(refname:lstrip=3)"`: remove the leftmost 3 chunks from the full ref name for a remote branch : `refs/remotes/origin/<keep only that part>`
- `git switch -C <branch> <tag>`: if for some reason a local `<branch>` already existed in your repo, `git switch <branch>` would switch to that branch, in its current state. With `-C` (uppercase `C`) and `<tag>`, you will always have a branch pointing at `<tag>`.